# xamarin Forms - Is it possible to get Grid row selection event?

Tags: xamarin, grid, xamarin.forms

How do i get row id of grid row selection? I want to add row unique id and i want it on tapped or on clicked. please suggest me if anyone have any idea.

I want to do some thing like this, if i click on the row and i get id. with this id i will fetch another records and send user on another page. for this i need unique id of the row.

i have grid like bellow:

[image]

Below is the code i use:

```
    public BusList(Common busdata)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = this;
        List<BusDetail> Bus = new List<BusDetail>
        {
            ...
            new BusDetail("Nita Travel","Mumbai", "Navsari",new DateTime(2017, 3, 9), "10:15 AM", "09:15 AM")
        };

        Label header = new Label
        {
            Text = "GridView Demo",
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)),
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        };


        var controlGrid = new Grid
        {

            RowSpacing = 2,
            ColumnSpacing = 2,
            Margin = new Thickness(5, Device.OnPlatform(5, 0, 0), 5, 5)
        };
        controlGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(30) });
        for (int i = 0; i < Bus.Count(); i++)
        {
            controlGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(30) });
        }
        controlGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
        controlGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
        controlGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
       controlGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });



        Bus = Bus.Where(x => x.FromDest.ToLower().Contains(busdata.FromDest.ToLower()) && x.FromDate == busdata.FromDate).ToList();
        controlGrid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "ID", Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize(NamedSize.Large).WithAttributes(FontAttributes.Bold), BackgroundColor = Color.Gray }, 0, 0);
        controlGrid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Travel Name", Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize(NamedSize.Large).WithAttributes(FontAttributes.Bold), BackgroundColor = Color.Gray }, 1, 0);
        controlGrid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Arr Time", Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize(NamedSize.Large).WithAttributes(FontAttributes.Bold), BackgroundColor = Color.Gray }, 2, 0);
        controlGrid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Dep Time", Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize(NamedSize.Large).WithAttributes(FontAttributes.Bold), BackgroundColor = Color.Gray }, 3, 0);


        for (int i = 0; i < Bus.Count(); i++)
        {
            var clickableRow = new ContentView();

            var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            tapGestureRecognizer.SetBinding(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandProperty, "RowTappedCommand");
            tapGestureRecognizer.SetBinding(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandParameterProperty, i.ToString()); 

            clickableRow.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
            clickableRow.BindingContext = i.ToString();
            controlGrid.Children.Add(clickableRow, 0, i);
            Grid.SetColumnSpan(clickableRow, 3);


            controlGrid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = Bus[i].TravelName, BindingContext = Bus[i].TravelName, BackgroundColor = Color.LightGray, VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center }, 1, i + 1);
            controlGrid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = Bus[i].ArrivalTime, BindingContext = Bus[i].ArrivalTime, BackgroundColor = Color.LightGray, VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center }, 2, i + 1);
            controlGrid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = Bus[i].DepartureTime, BindingContext= Bus[i].DepartureTime, BackgroundColor = Color.LightGray, VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center }, 3, i + 1);

        }
        this.Padding = new Thickness(10, Device.OnPlatform(20, 0, 0), 10, 5);
        this.Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children =
            {
                header,
                controlGrid
            }
        };
    }

  public  void RowTappedCommand(string index)
    {
        var tappedRow = int.Parse(index);

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a `ContentView` to each row on the first column and span it across all columns by using the `ColumnSpan` property. Then you'd handle the taps with a `TouchGestureListener`. When creating the `Command`, you'd also include a `CommandParameter` which contains the index of the row in question.

Outside the constructor, define this:

```
public ICommand RowTappedCommand { get; private set; }
```

Then add the following code somewhere after InitializeComponent:

```
RowTappedCommand = new Command<string>(RowTapped);
```

Then create the clickable ContentView controls for each row:

```
var clickableRow = new ContentView {
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
}

var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
tapGestureRecognizer.SetBinding(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandProperty, "RowTappedCommand");
var binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = i.ToString();
tapGestureRecognizer.SetBinding(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandParameterProperty, binding); // This is the index of the row
clickableRow.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);

controlGrid.Children.Add(clickableRow, 0, 0);
Grid.SetColumnSpan(clickableRow,3);
```

You also need to define the method that matches the name defined in the `CommandProperty`. If you have a view model defined for the view you need to do it there. Otherwise, you'll need to add the method to your view's code behind file (xaml.cs).

```
void RowTapped(string index)
{
    var tappedRow = int.Parse(index);
    // Do something with the value
}
```

Remember to set the BindingContext correctly so that your command gets called. Here's more information about Commands in Xamarin.Forms:

---

**Update:** There were a few mistakes that needed to be fixed.

1. Command wasn't defined correctly.
2. The binding for the command property needs to be pointing to a static value

[Simplifying Events with Commanding](https://blog.xamarin.com/simplifying-events-with-commanding/)

Comment: Thanks for reply @hankide, i have one more question is how do i use this? i have to make any method?? sorry for my question, but i am new in xamarin so please help me.

Comment: i added this code in .cs file but it is not working. i am not getting call in RowTappedCommand method. please help me to solve this.

Comment: @Dhruti Have you set the binding context?

Comment: @Dhruti If all your code is in the code behind file, put this after InitializeComponent in the constructor: `this.BindingContext = this`. That way the command will be found and called correctly.

Comment: yes i have set. is it correct to set binding contect?  controlGrid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = Bus[i].TravelName, BindingContext = Bus[i].TravelName, BackgroundColor = Color.LightGray, VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center }, 1,1);

Comment: To get this work the simplest way you don't have to change the way you add labels (even though it would be more effective using bindings in XAML). See my latest comment. You need to define BindingContext in the constructor and then use the code I provided to add the contentview to each row.

Comment: @Dhruti Can you post the full code so I can see where it goes wrong?

Comment: @Dhruti Try to add the clickableRow after you add the TravelName, ArrivalTime and DepartureTime labels. Also, make sure you add them to the same row. Right now the labels are at row i+1 while the clickableRow is on row i. Make them both i or i+1.

Comment: @Dhruti I forgot HorizontalOptions and VerticalOptions from my code. Please see the update.

Comment: @Dhruti For starters, remove this `clickableRow.BindingContext = i.ToString();`  Also, you don't need to set the BindingContext anywhere else but in the beginning of the method. You don't need to do it for the labels either. I'm not sure if it'll fix it but that's a start.

Comment: Thank you for this much your efforts but still it is not working.

Comment: @Dhruti See the latest update. There are changes to all code blocks so make sure to get them all.

Comment: @Dhruti Did you get it to work? I verified it on my end and the latest solution works.

Comment: no it is not work for me. i got the call from method but i am getting (null) in index.

Comment: @Dhruti That's what happened to me too at first. Could you once more update your code on the main post? Did you remember to add the `var binding = new Binding();` thing from the biggest code block?

Comment: I would suggest to use a listview inside a data grid. I have a code example on how I solved this issue here. With list view you can still have the ItemSelected. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48167477/xamarin-listview-dynamic-column-width/48174828#48174828